# Proof: Let $a_n\underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow}\infty $ a posit sequence so $ \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_n}}=\infty $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

The question is:
Proove that for a positive sequence $a_n$  s.t. $\lim_{n \to \infty }a_n=\infty $ so $   \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_n}}=\infty   $

Here my proof:
Let writte $b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$ and so $\lim_{n \to \infty }b_n=0$
Now let define the Cesaro sum as follow: $C_n=\frac{b_1+b_3+...+b_n}{n}$ . So by the cesaro theorem $\lim_{n \to \infty } C_n = 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty } b_n$
It cames naturally that $\frac{1}{C_n}=\frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_n}}\underset{n \to \infty }{\rightarrow}0$ because $\lim_{n \to \infty } C_n=0\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty } 1/C_n=\infty $ Q.E.D.

Is it correct? If this is correct and you have other idea to prove what it please post it as an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you can you post it as an answer so i can mark this topic as solved? Or if you have any other idea to prove it i will be happy to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proof is correct. If anyone as an other/better solution i will be happy to read it. (I just writte this answer to mark my question as solved)